# How do I fix this NGINX 502 Bad Gateway error?

Tags: nginx, websocket, http-status-code-502

I'm working on web sockets in an angular app.  I have it connect to a python back-end through nginx.  I'm find that I'm getting 502 "Bad Gateway" errors about 90% of the time.  I'll do this:

1. Load page in browser and connect web socket
2. Python back-end sends data to angular front-end
3. Disconnect web socket
4. Attempt to re-connect web socket <-- 502 Bad Gateway error
5. Hard-reload in Chrome
6. Load page in browser and connect web socket <-- No 502 error

I can't figure out why this is happening.  I can't tell why I'm getting a 502 error.  Nor can I figure out why doing a hard-reload fixes the problem.  Things I've tried:

- Increase nginx log-level to debug.  Still the logs don't have any useful information.
- I don't keep any web socket objects in state.  I do this in case something is being cached somewhere.
- I always close the web socket with close code 1000
- I manually run the python service on the server so that I can watch it.  When the 502 error happens, the service doesn't show anything unusual.
- Setting the nginx max_fails to 0.  Setting the fail_timeout to 0.  Neither of these changes seems to have any effect.  (I found this suggestion in other SO answers)

What should I be looking for that will help me fix this problem?

EDIT:  Here's my nginx conf.d file:

```
server {
  listen  80;

  index index.html;
  root /var/www/mysite;

  location / {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite/ui.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite/ui.error.log;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /ws/ {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_pass http://WEBSOCKET/;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite/ws_services.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite/ws_services.error.log;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
  }
}

upstream WEBSOCKET {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8765;
}
```

Comment: What's the stack for the Python service? Both the framework on the Python side of things and the app server running it?

Comment: It's Python 3.6 on CentOS Linux.  I'm importing just the standard websockets library. I'm actually running the command manually, though I usually run it as a daemon.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: There is no module in the Python standard library that provides websockets. You will have to provide some (preferably minimal) code here.

Comment: @AKX I have this line in my requirements.txt file  `websockets==8.0.1`  I'll include my nginx code as an edit to my question

Comment: Which app server is running your app? (The process that's listening on port 8765.)

Comment: I have python code that's listening to port 8765.  I'm running it manually in order to watch is closely.  I'll usually run it in systemd.

Comment: ... And what do you do in that Python code to have it listen on port 8765?

Answer (score 4):

Not the same problem the OP had, but just in case anyone comes across this and has the same setup as I had:

I was using WebSockets over SSL (so `wss://` protocol) and had 502 popping up, even though the config had worked before. The config was as follows:

```
...
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
...
```

In the backend I was using a Node with the `ws` package to create a websocket server

As I said: It was working before, but suddenly stopped working. Additionally nginx wrote `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream` errors into the error log. I suppose that either nginx or node closed some kind of security issue, that lead to the setup not working anymore.

What I had to do in order to make it work, was to use https instead of http for the `proxy_pass` config

```
...
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080;
...
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and tried your solution. In the process, I noticed another error that caused the container to restart itself relatively frequently. After fixing this other problem, I switched back from HTTPS to HTTP for fun. Lo and behold: the problem is gone.

Comment: Fixed it, thx. In my case, nodejs app was started as a SSL app, and nginx sent to http instead of https.